# Best way to transfer RSA-encrypted data over TCP?

Tags: c, openssl

I am implementing a decrypting mix-net in C using OpenSSL.

I have encrypted the data using EVP_SealInit, EVP_SealUpdate, and EVP_SealFinal.  I would then like to transfer this data over TCP to an open port (the first "mix").

Is EVP_SealInit, etc. the best way to go about encrypting a message string to be sent over TCP?

And if that's the case, how do i transfer the IV over this connection?  I mean: i can think of a few ways, but i guess i don't see the point of having an IV if i'm just going to transmit it with the message.  Is it possible to set the IV to some value, such as all zeroes?  How would i go about doing that?

I'm happy to post code if it helps.

Comment: traditionally the IV is included as the preamble to the encrypted data. Since the algorithm is known, the size of the IV will be as well. On the receive-side simply pull the IV off first. And as Pavel stated, if you're using a random session key, the IV becomes irrelevant (though still part of the algorithm) and you can use a 0-filled IV on both ends and not worry about sending it. The 'prepend as the preamble' of the IV is what Pavel is talking about when he says you need a protocol, and his answer is totally correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something that you can call a protocol. In its terms you will know when to send a data, when to send an IV, etc.

IV can also be zero if your session key is random each time (EVP_Seal... provides that).

Comment: Thank you both! (Sorry, hit return too soon)
Unfortunately i realized this morning that because will be encrypting a message 5 times (it will then be decrypted in reverse order by the mix net), i will end up with five different IVs to transmit.  I think the best thing to do would be to use unique session keys.  
In that case, how do i set my IV to zero?  I tried supplying NULL to SealInit (as the documentation suggests is possible), but my code segfaults.  TIA!

Comment: Zero IV is not meaning NULL pointer. You must provide a pointer to a valid IV (memory block same size that cipher block, 16 bytes for AES). But it can be constant and is zero bytes block for most implementations.